# We changed our domain a year ago to .com but old site is still number one when searching

Tags: domains, htaccess, search-engines, redirects

I changed our companies domain name a year ago from radfan.co.uk to radfan.com. When typing radfan into Google the number one result is still radfan.co.uk rather than the .com. This is not the case for Bing and Yahoo.

This is the .htaccess rule I have used

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^radfan\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.radfan\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.radfan\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Is there something else I need to do?

UPDATE:

Turns out if I search for radfan.com google finds it but asks if I meant "radfan.co.uk" ...

UPDATE 2:

I moved the domain in January 2012, so 14 months now

Comment: A year ago, did you notice Google your domain was changed in Google Webmaster Tools?

Comment: I didn't set up webmaster tools for the old domain as I knew it would be temporary, I did for the .com and never noticed that .co.uk was still the number 1 hit when searching for radfan.

Comment: Is the RewriteCond active on the old site? Mostly, you have separate folders for different domains on your host, you need to have this RewriteCond in the htaccess of your old domain, not the new one.

Comment: How long ago did you redirect .co.uk to .com? as things like this can take a while, I've seen sites appear like this for 3 months or more. Also!! You may want to remove <head><div id="fb-root"></div></head> out of the header :P

Comment: I moved the domain in January 2012, so 14 months now, thank for the fb-root tip - copy past error :-(

Comment: Its and odd one indeed since I've heard of sites taking months to even a year but normally these are sites that are extremely HIGH volume paged based ones and not one so small as yours. Have you told Google you moved domain via the Webmaster Tools?

Comment: I've just managed to do that, I had some verification issues but sorted now. Do you think it will help?

Comment: yes!!.. deffo ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you did is fine. The search results that you see may appear only to you as part of the personalized search results.
This may be due to your search history settings. Here is a guide on [how to disable this feature](https://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=54057)

Comment: Sadly I don't think this is that case as I don't have Google web history enabled on my account and running any browser in private mode still brings up the same result ...

Answer (score 1):

Alright then, can you please try this instead:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

While replacing `http://www.newdomain.com` with `http://www.radfan.com`
Also, verify that the Apache Mod-Rewrite module is enabled (just to be sure)
And verify also if you still have backlinks pointing to your old domain.

Comment: Ok, how will I know if it's worked? Won't to google results take a few days to update?I'm fairly sure the rewrite engine is on as typing radfan.co.uk in the adress bar takes me to radfan.com. There will be some links to the old site but all of the important ones will be to the .com as the change has been for over a year.

Comment: @Mohamed Anis Dahmani: Please don't answer twice, edit your first one.

Comment: Thank you for your kind advice Zistoloen.
@SimonBarker: When I search radfan I find radfan.com on first place.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that your results are localized to your country. I am in Canada and when I google "radfan", *radfan.com* is #2. #1 is a wikipedia entry, and there are no listings for *radfan.co.uk* on page one.

I am pretty sure there is nothing better you can do with your rewrite rule.